# ERROR 2013 (HY000) trying to import mariadb database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am migrating a nextcloud server from a raspberry pi 3 running raspian stretch to an rpi 4 running raspian buster. One step is to dump a mariadb database and import in on the new server. I created a dump of the mariadb database (the database dump file is 120MB) and am tyring to restore it with the following commands:

```
mysql -h localhost -u nextcloud -p<password> -e "CREATE DATABASE nextcloud"

mysql -h localhost -uroot -p<password> -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on nextcloud.* to nextcloud@localhost"

mysql -h localhost -u nextcloud -p<password> nextcloud < <backup_db_file>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 746: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Bsed on google searching, I tried modifying my mariadb configuration file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf so it is like this:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 160M
net_read_timeout = 300
net_write_timeout = 600
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 160M
```

But I get the same error. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong, or how I can work around this?

The raspberry pi 4 has 4 GB of ram in case it's relevant

Answer (score 0):

So, actually, I rebooted the server, and after that the database could be imported. I thought the new settings would be picked up when I restarted the mysql service, which I certainly attempted to do before rebooting.